# MySql workbench 8.0.31 on Ubuntu 22.04 looks like gibberish

Tags: 22.04, mysql, mysql-workbench

I just installed and reinstalled MySQL Workbench Community 8.0.31-1 on Ubuntu 22.04 but when I open it through the icon or the terminal window it looks like gibberish. I'm running Ubuntu through VirtualBox on a 4K display with 3840x2160 resolution, and I don't know if it has something to do with it. I had to increase the VirtualBox max resolution to 256MB to take full advantage of the display resolution.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: A question about visual appearance is pretty much impossible to answer without a screenshot.

Comment: A link to the picture was added

Comment: That looks like Arabic or Hebrew or Kanji characters to me. Try typing `locale` in that terminal (if it lets you type Latin characters) and, if it does something, paste the output (formatted as "code" with 3 backticks ```) to the end of your problem description.

Comment: The top-center row has normal latin characters, I can make out a `y` and a `b`, but they are somehow displayed clipped, sliced. I would definitely vote for the involvement of a graphics driver. Test out whether the same thing happens with smaller screen resolutions.